# Wrap span around only numbers with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

How can I wrap a `span` around the numbers (and only the numbers) in the table cells with class "data" and not the `$` character?

Here's the HTML markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Views</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Item description here</td>
        <td class="data">37 pounds</td>
        <td class="data">132 views</td>
        <td class="data">$99.59</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you have tried to achieve what your looking for?

Comment: You could look at the chars in string one by one and when you reach the first digit, you could put `<span>` in front of it, similar with the first following non-digit char and `</span>` or you can use `regular expression` and `.replace()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a jQuery beginner and I have absolutely no idea about how to do this... I've been researching in stackoverflow's answers but haven't found anything.

Comment: @amp511 This is rather a question about JavaScript and Regular Expressions in general. I strongly recommend you to visit [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) to learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm starting to learn and I've been trying to do it by myself but couldn't achieve the effect. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @amp511 You should have added what you tried to the question. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match the numbers and wrap them with a `span`.

```
var rxp = new RegExp("([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)", "gm");
$("td.data").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var content = $this.html();
    $this.html(content.replace(rxp, "<span>$1</span>"));
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZXMe/1/)

Comment: this regex only wrap up more than 1 digit number. When you a single digit number, it wont wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
var searchPattern = new RegExp(/^\d+$/, 'g');
$elem = $('td.data');
$elem.html($elem.html().replace(searchPattern , "<span>" + searchPattern  + "</span>"));
```

Where, $elem is the jQuery object for the HTML element you are searching in, i.e. all TD with class 'data'.

Comment: You didn't take into account presence of dots and that digits can be not from begining and not in the end of td.